# A get or set accessor expected enum

Tags: c#, enums

I am getting the following compilation error when trying to create an Enum:

> "A get or set accessor expected"

This is the code:

```
private Enum HolidayCalendarType
{
    BusinessDays,
    CalendarDays,        
}
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 10):

The keyword `enum` should be in lower case when defining it. The following declaration works:

```
private enum HolidayCalendarType
{
    BusinessDays,
    CalendarDays        
}
```

Whereas `Enum` (Pascal case) helps to provide the base class for enumerations.

Comment: I've never seen this issue anywhere, seems like a redundant self answer :/

Comment: Just now I got this problem and searched but didn't find the answer, later copied another enum and found the difference.